# Using SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION for package version inside Docker with .git directory in dockerignore

Tags: python, docker, version-control, setuptools

I'm using [setuptools scm](https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/) to dynamically provide version numbers for a Python package, and have these lines in the pyproject.toml:

```
...
dynamic = ["dependencies", "version", "readme"]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["my_package"]

[tool.setuptools_scm]
...
```

When I try to install the package inside Docker, the process fails because I have included the *.git* directory in the .dockerignore.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-runtime

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    build-essential curl wget git sox ffmpeg libsndfile1 zip unzip mandoc groff

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install && \
    rm awscliv2.zip

WORKDIR /workspace

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --root-user-action=ignore --no-cache-dir --no-deps -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN ./scripts/install_custom_requirements.sh

ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION=$VERSION

RUN SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION=$(python -m setuptools_scm) pip install --root-user-action=ignore --no-cache-dir --no-deps .
```

For clarity, this is the line I have in my .dockerignore:

```
**/.git
```

When I comment out the line, my Docker build works fine, but I don't want to copy *everything* across when I do `COPY . .` in the Dockerfile.

How can I keep the `**/.git` in my .dockerignore whilst getting setuptools scm to provide the version dynamically?

The [documentation (see section "with Docker / Podman")](https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/) says:

> To avoid BuildKit and mounting of the .git folder altogether, one can also pass the desired version as a build argument. Note that SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION_FOR_${NORMALIZED_DIST_NAME} is preferred over SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION.

But when I tried to pass this environment variable, the build failed. Here is what I tried:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

source vars.env

VERSION=$(git describe --tags --dirty --always)

git submodule update --init --recursive --progress

docker build \
    --progress=plain \
    --build-arg "VERSION=${VERSION}" \
    -t "${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:${VERSION}" \
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer; there is just a minor mistake:

```
# In the Dockerfile, you are using
ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION=$VERSION

# When, from the docs you cited, it should have been
ARG VERSION
ENV SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION=$VERSION

# or, even better
ENV SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION_FOR_MY_PACKAGE=$VERSION

# Then you can change the RUN directive to
RUN pip install --root-user-action=ignore --no-cache-dir --no-deps .
```

Furthermore, there may be an issue with the difference between the version format expected by setuptools and the one provided by git.
You can try using a regex like this one to solve the issue. Personalize it based on your needs.

```bash
VERSION=$(git describe --tags --always --dirty | sed -r 's/-([0-9]+)/.dev\1/' | sed 's/-/+/')
```